# Mail Server Setup, MX Records, and Hostnames?

Tags: email, dns, postfix

I'm a bit confused how mail servers work, and the process of setting them up. Say I have an domain called example.com, and I have an A record for it. I'll be using postfix/dovecot for this setup along with an SSL certificate.

When setting all this up, do I create a new A record for mail.example.com, as well as a MX record for mail.example.com, and assign the cert to mail.example.com, even though all mail is being sent to example.com accounts? Will this work, or does everything need to be pointed to just example.com?

In all the documentation I've read, everything says set up the mail server as a subdomain, and assign all the hostnames, MX records, A records (for webmail), and SSL certs to that. Just want to make sure I'm on the right path here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you've got it right. Do all of that.

Here's why:

Usually (and traditionally) `example.com` does not resolve to an actual host, or is the same as `www`. In order to decouple the domain name from the host that handles mail delivery for a domain name, a separate mail exchanger (MX) is designated.

When mail is destined to `example.com` the sending (or relaying) MTA will look up the MX for `example.com`. If more than one MX is returned connections will be attempted to each in priority order. When the sending MTA contacts the MX the hostname specified in the MX must match the certificate supplied by the server in order to validate properly.

If there are no MX records for `example.com` then the sending MTA look up the A record for and attempt to contact `example.com` directly. If there's no A or CNAME the message will be bounced.

Comment: To be clear, the MX record needs to be at `example.com`, not `mail.example.com`.

Comment: But should mail and ssl certs be pointed to mail.example.com? It seems that @bahamat says that everything needs MX records for the sub, ssl certs to the sub, and postfix hosts to the sub. Will that work is an email is directed to just user@example.com?

Comment: Yes, the certificate should be for the sub. If the MX record for `example.com` is `foo.example.com`, then remote mail servers will connect to `foo.example.com`. They will expect it to answer with a cert for `foo.example.com`.